# Jump to line in vim with relativenumber on

Tags: ide, vim

In a normal situation it's possible to look at the line number and use [number]G to goto that line. But I like to work with the setting relativenumber on. The disadvantage is that I can't jump to lines anymore by looking at the displayed line number.

Is it possible to redefine the behavior of [number]G to fix this? Also, would it be possible to make the current line number 1 instead of 0 with relativenumber on? And how?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can simply `[number]j` or `[number]k` to do this.

Comment: Or `[number]-` and `[number]+`.

Comment: These motions do not populate in the jump list

Comment: Or  `[number] ↑` and `[number] ↓`